# Java and SSL on localhost

Tags: java, sockets, ssl

I'm trying to trial a SSLServerSocket program on my local machine - (the program is intended to use either plain sockets or SSL sockets based on a single parameter to the constructor of the server object). In plain data, the program works exactly as expected, but with SSL:

```
socket.getInputStream().read();
```

Always returns 65535 (i.e. 0xFFFF), even when the remote end is closed. Any idea what's wrong? I can post code if that helps.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Ok, now I'm awake - as the person below correctly pointed out, its a 'disconnect' sortof (isClosed still returns false, etc, but the input stream only has -1's).

Looking at the debug information for SSL, I noticed this gem:

```
***
pool-2-thread-1, WRITE: TLSv1.1 Handshake, length = 36
%% Cached server session: [Session-3, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA]
pool-2-thread-1, received EOFException: ignored
pool-2-thread-1, called closeInternal(false)
pool-2-thread-1, SEND TLSv1.1 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
pool-2-thread-1, WRITE: TLSv1.1 Alert, length = 22
pool-2-thread-1, called closeSocket(selfInitiated)
After use
```

From the code:

```
final SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) ((SSLServerSocket)_ServerSocket).accept();
System.out.println("Before use");
socket.getInputStream().read();
System.out.println("After use");
```

So, I -think- the client end (in this case, a browser) is hanging up without properly saying 'goodbye'.

Given my intended use is a websocket over SSL/TLS (wss://localhost:/), I've tried adding a certificate setup and adding it to Windows 7's trusted certificates, but it still doesn't seem to want to work (the html file is on my local system, and the connection is to the wss: URL above, so should the server alias for keygen.exe be localhost?).

Any idea where I'm going wrong still?

Comment: Instead of re-inventing a wheel, there are websocket implementations in the Netty, and Apache MINA, Jetty, and Resin frameworks I think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mistaken. read() never returns 0xFFFF. However it returns *-1* (0xFFFFFFFF) when the peer has closed. See the Javadoc. You need to store the result in an int, not a byte, so you can distinguish -1 meaning EOS from 0xFF as a byte of data.